Trying to Web Scrape in Python
I am trying to extract a flow of the URL but am stuck. The URL from where I am extracting data, redirects to a page, which has the URL which then has to be clicked to go to the page's URL I actually want to scrape.
This is the source url:
http://ndl.iitkgp.ac.in/nw_document/economictimes/IN__T_E_T___2__1_2001__3_12__65_05__23_71
This is what appears when I click the url within the source urls
I need to code a way to use just source the URL to extract the final URL that will appear when you click the button.
Using Selenium, WebDriver, Beautiful Soup packages.
A section of code. It cannot find the specific link I wanted -
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')

# Find the final URL based on the given HTML structure
final_link = soup.find('a', class_='btn btn-success', href=True)

if final_link:
    final_url = final_link['href']
    print(f"Found final URL: {final_url}")
    posts_urls.append(final_url)
else:
    print("No final URL found in the expected format.")


Try:
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

id_ = "IN__T_E_T___2__1_2001__3_12__65_05__23_71"

# this is <iframe> URL that has actual content
viewer_url = "https://ndl.iitkgp.ac.in/module-viewer/viewer.php?id=economictimes/economictimes/{}&domain=nw"


def get_page(id_):
    headers = {"Referer": f"http://ndl.iitkgp.ac.in/nw_document/economictimes/{id_}"}
    soup = BeautifulSoup(
        requests.get(viewer_url.format(id_), headers=headers).content, "html.parser"
    )
    return soup


def get_sub_ids(id_):
    soup = get_page(id_)
    return [a["href"].split("/")[-1] for a in soup.select("a")]


sub_ids = get_sub_ids(id_)  # sub_ids = ['37230_2', '37230_3', '37230_4', '37230_1']
for s in sub_ids:
    url = get_page(s).select_one(".btn")["href"]
    print(s, url)

Prints:
37230_2 https://economictimes.indiatimes.com/news/economy/policy/yield-spread-crashes-prophesies-economy-gloom/articleshow/332850363.cms
37230_3 https://economictimes.indiatimes.com/news/economy/policy/supplementary-demands-approved/articleshow/1219281788.cms
37230_4 https://economictimes.indiatimes.com/news/economy/policy/shourie-seeks-ags-advice-on-itdc-hotel-sale/articleshow/1436743634.cms
37230_1 https://economictimes.indiatimes.com/news/economy/policy/govt-hints-at-removing-poto-provisions-affecting-media/articleshow/882241993.cms


Hi. I used this code, and it worked to extract where there were a small number of posts. But its not functioning for when the posts, exceed the visible page, like in link below. I tried using infinite scroll to see if it will give me a complete set of url, but didnt work. Its only giving 10-20 instead of 100.
http://ndl.iitkgp.ac.in/nw_document/economictimes/IN__T_E_T___2__1_2018__2278_10__5_17__7_6442

for the specific economictimes example, the code would look like this:
import re
import http.client

host = "ndl.iitkgp.ac.in"

sub_path = "/nw_document/economictimes/"
sub_endpoint = "IN__T_E_T___2__1_2001__3_12__65_05__23_71"

art_headers = {"Referer": sub_path}
art_path = "/module-viewer/viewer.php?id=economictimes/economictimes/%s"

sub_pattern = re.compile(r'%s(\d{5}_\d)' % sub_path, re.M)
art_pattern = re.compile(r'f="([^"]+\.cms)', re.M)

conn = http.client.HTTPConnection(host)

conn.request("GET", sub_path + sub_endpoint)
response = conn.getresponse()
html_content = response.read().decode()

art_endpoints = [match.group(1) for match in sub_pattern.finditer(html_content)]
art_urls = []
for art_endpoint in art_endpoints:
    conn.request("GET", art_path % art_endpoint, headers=art_headers)
    response = conn.getresponse()
    html_content = response.read().decode()

    art_url = art_pattern.search(html_content)
    art_urls.append(art_url.group(1))

print(*art_urls, sep="\n")


output:
https://economictimes.indiatimes.com/news/economy/policy/yield-spread-crashes-prophesies-economy-gloom/articleshow/332850363.cms
https://economictimes.indiatimes.com/news/economy/policy/supplementary-demands-approved/articleshow/1219281788.cms
https://economictimes.indiatimes.com/news/economy/policy/shourie-seeks-ags-advice-on-itdc-hotel-sale/articleshow/1436743634.cms
https://economictimes.indiatimes.com/news/economy/policy/govt-hints-at-removing-poto-provisions-affecting-media/articleshow/882241993.cms

